# how to summarize values depending on checked box

Tags: javascript, vue.js, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to add the numbers together as a summarized value depending on which item is checked to display as total on my checkout page.

I have tried

```
if ( this.products[0].selected === true ) {
this.summary = this.products[0].price
} else if ( this.products[0].selected === true, this.products[1].selected === true  ) {
this.summary = this.products[0].price + this.products[1].price 
} else {
this.summary = 0;
}
```

Obviously no the full statement but it didn't even work this far.

I have an array of objects containing this

```
data: {
  summary: 0,
  products: [
    { name: 'Hemsida', price: 290, selected: false },
    { name: 'Copywriting', price: 190, selected: false },
    { name: 'Fotografering', price: 190, selected: false }
  ]
}
```

and when i check my box it turns the linked to !products[0].selected

My latest try was with a switch statement, I might have totally butchered it, since this is my first switch statement on the field :P

```
  priceSummary() {
    switch (
      (this.products[0].selected,
      this.products[1].selected,
      this.products[2].selected)
    ) {
      case (true, false, false):
        this.summary = this.products[0].price
        break
      case (true, true, false):
        this.summary = this.products[0].price + this.products[1].price
        break
      case (true, false, true):
        this.summary = this.products[0].price + this.products[2].price
        break
      case (false, false, true):
        this.summary = this.products[2].price
        break
      case (false, true, false):
        this.summary = this.products[1].price
        break
      case (false, false, false):
        this.summary = 0
        break
      case (true, true, true):
        this.summary =
          this.products[0].price +
          this.products[1].price +
          this.products[2].price
      default:
        this.summary = 0
    }
```

It does something, but it doesn't do what it should :P kind of all over the place. help anyone???

Comment: The big downside of not using a loop is that you have to change the if/else or switch for Every product you add. You can see how this will be not doable when you have a shop with thousands of different products. Calculating the total price should not depend on how many items you're buying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethings like that :

```
//looping on products
this.product.forEach((prod) => {
 //checking if product is selected
 if(prod.selected === true){
  // if it's selected, adding its price to the sum
  this.summary += prod.price
 }
}
```

?

Comment: Thank you man, this one did the job, I also left out === true (prod.selected) is enough. And also added this.summary = 0, so that it doesnt keep on adding to the summary even if checked off and on multiple times :)

Comment: You're welcome, happy to see you've got no problems for adjustment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use array methods, each step can be really easy and readable.
Apart from a few edge cases, a switch statement should not replace a loop.

```js
const model = {
  data: {
    summary: 0,
    products: [
      { name: 'Hemsida', price: 290, selected: true },
      { name: 'Copywriting', price: 190, selected: true },
      { name: 'Fotografering', price: 190, selected: false }
    ]
  }
};
// Create an array of only selected products.
const selected_products = model.data.products.filter( product => product.selected );
// Sum the prices of the selected products.
const price = selected_products.reduce(( sum, product ) => sum + product.price, 0 );

model.data.summary = price;

console.log( model.data.summary );
```

Comment: will try this one out also, thx for the input. I am just starting out as a programmer and make rookie mistakes everyday.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is as @Nil says above. But if you want "non-iterable" version without loop you can do it like this:

```js
priceSummary() {
    this.summary = 0

    if(this.products[0].selected) {
        this.summary += this.products[0].price // same as this.summary = this.summary + this.products[0].price
    }

    if(this.products[1].selected) {
        this.summary += this.products[1].price
    }

    if(this.products[2].selected) {
        this.summary += this.products[2].price
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I included this.summary = 0 in the start of Nils version and it works like a dream. So did your version, but Nils way was more clean :D

Comment: So merge them both: before `this.product.forEach` put `this.summary = 0` :)